# "Is it persuasive for sth to do" is not grammatical construction?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, adjectives

> 1. Is **it** persuasive **for** an adjective **to** take a nominal
>      complement directly?

Would you tell me If that's ungrammatical? If so, what did you think of the following?

> 2. Is **it** persuasive **that** an adjective takes a nominal complement directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example sentence is grammatically correct, in that "persuasive" can be replaced by another adjective, and the resulting sentence will make sense:

> 3. Is **it** acceptable **for** an adjective **to** take a nominal
>      complement directly?
> 4. Is **it** valid **for** an adjective **to** take a nominal
>      complement directly?

However, the word "persuasive" does not make sense in this context.  I do not understand how "an adjective [taking] a nominal complement directly" would make a sentence more convincing.